# Can you access a spreadsheet using the Google Drive API that doesn't belong to you, assuming you are authenticated?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api

I have a spreadsheet that my client wishes to keep private. They also wish to sell the information that can be calculated using it (its really complicated, with lots of up to date information in it).

My approach has been to create a web application that users can log into. I'm then hoping to make the web application access the spreadsheet using the Google Spreadsheet API.

#### The problem:

So far everything I'm trying is actually logging me in as a user to access the spreadsheet. I'm concerned that this technique is incorrect: its the web app that should be authenticated, not the Google User.

So, very convoluted, but finally my question: is it possible to authenticate a web app, not a Google user, to access a spreadsheet stored in Google drive? Hence, hiding the spreadsheet from them.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is for you to make web app proxying spreadsheet with "Anyone with a link" on Sharing setting of Google Drive. Your web app can authenticate buyers and show caching a link read-only spreadsheet link to them.